# How can i optimize my code, that works with much numbers?

Tags: python, optimization

I wrote the following python function:

```
def ritornaoccorenzeinlista(listainput, listaricercati, rangeiniziale, rangefinale, condizionenormale):
listarisultato = []

for y in range(len(listainput)):
    contatore = 0
    for x in range(len(listaricercati)):
        if listaricercati[x] in listainput[y]:
            contatore += 1

    if rangeiniziale <= contatore <= rangefinale and condizionenormale:
        listarisultato.append(listainput[y])
    if (contatore < rangeiniziale or contatore > rangefinale) and (not condizionenormale):
        listarisultato.append(listainput[y])

return listarisultato
```

The function have the following argument:

```
ritornaoccorenzeinlista(list listainput[[]], list listaricercati[], int rangeiniziale, int rangefinale, bool condizionenormale)
```

I did some benchmarks:

```
-------------1----------------
len(listainput)=252
len(listaricercati)=900000
rangeiniziale=85000
rangefinale=100000
condizionenormale= True
ExecutionTime= 38.512633323669434 seconds
```

```
-------------2----------------
len(listainput)=252
len(listaricercati)=900000
rangeiniziale=85000
rangefinale=100000
condizionenormale= False
ExecutionTime= 37.751357555389404 seconds
```

Since i'm working with much number i would like to make the function as fast as possible.

Do you have any possible suggest to apply?

Thank you.

Edit Update:
1) adding counter:

```
def ritornaoccorenzeinlista(listainput, listaricercati, rangeiniziale, rangefinale, condizionenormale):
    listarisultato = []

    for y in range(len(listainput)):
        contatore = 0
        listaconcounter = Counter(listainput[y])
        for x in range(len(listaricercati)):
            if listaconcounter[listaricercati[x]]>0:
                contatore += 1

        if rangeiniziale <= contatore <= rangefinale and condizionenormale:
            listarisultato.append(listainput[y])
        if (contatore < rangeiniziale or contatore > rangefinale) and (not condizionenormale):
            listarisultato.append(listainput[y])

    return listarisultato
```

benchmark:

```
-------------3----------------
len(listainput)=252
len(listaricercati)=900000
rangeiniziale=85000
rangefinale=100000
condizionenormale= True
ExecutionTime= 75.9251697063446 seconds
```

Edit Update:
2) adding counter in a better way:

```
def ritornaoccorenzeinlista(listainput, listaricercati, rangeiniziale, rangefinale, condizionenormale):
    listarisultato = []
    listaricercati=Counter(listaricercati).most_common()
    for y in range(len(listainput)):
        contatore = 0
        for x in range(len(listaricercati)):
            if listaricercati[x][0] in listainput[y]:
                contatore += 1*listaricercati[x][1]

        if rangeiniziale <= contatore <= rangefinale and condizionenormale:
            listarisultato.append(listainput[y])
        if (contatore < rangeiniziale or contatore > rangefinale) and (not condizionenormale):
            listarisultato.append(listainput[y])

    return listarisultato
```

Benchmark:

```
-------------1----------------
len(listainput)=252
len(listaricercati)=900000
rangeiniziale=85000
rangefinale=100000
condizionenormale= True
ExecutionTime= 0.059412479400634766 seconds
```

Edit Update: 
3) Translate function and add some output as example:

```
inputlist=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
#each inputlist[x] contain different numbers
listnumbertofind=[1,2,2,3,6,11,1,7,1]
#listnumbertofind could contain repeated numbers
startrange=2
finishrange=4
boolean=True
#boolean can be True or False based on how the function get called
#the function should return the elements of inputlist[] that contains 2<listnumbertofind[x]<4


def ritornaoccorenzeinlista(inputlist, listnumbertofind, startrange, finishrange, boolean):
    listarisultato = []
    listnumbertofind=Counter(listnumbertofind).most_common()
    for y in range(len(inputlist)):
        contatore = 0
        for x in range(len(listnumbertofind)):
            if listnumbertofind[x][0] in inputlist[y]:
                contatore += 1*listnumbertofind[x][1]

        if startrange <= contatore <= finishrange and boolean:
            listarisultato.append(inputlist[y])
        if (contatore < startrange or contatore > finishrange) and (not boolean):
            listarisultato.append(inputlist[y])

    return listarisultato
```

Example output using the values reported up:

```
[[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: You seem to be checking if any number from onelist is in the other list - and count how often. Use collection.Counter instead. and use sets to avoid checking duplicates numbrs over and over again.

Comment: The question is how duplicates should be treated, for example if a number occurs twice in both lists, should the count be 1, 2 or 4?

Comment: Strongly recommend you check out the [PEP8 style guide for variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45). Not everyone agrees with everything in here, and a lot is up to personal preference, but I've never seen variables with multiple words, all lowercase, and no underscores. Extremely difficult to read. PEP8 recommends `lowercase_with_underscores` for local variables and function names.

Comment: Hello @PatrickArtner, i tried adding collection.counter but it looks like it slower, i updated the code that i used up, you can find the benhmark.
Please le me know if i used it well or if i did it wrong.
Now i will try to just adds sets.

Comment: Please translate the variable names into english and explain what this does. Provide hardcoded inputdata as example how this is run and add the expected results showing _why_ you would expect this. Your code has a for loop with another for loop which is at least quadratic - adding Counter additionally on top does not help. You would use it instead. Currently i am still not sure what your algo accomplishes and what data it is run on.

Comment: Hello @PatrickArtner yes your right, i implemented the counter not well, i did it in a better way, now the code get run in 0.059412479400634766 seconds.
I will translate the function in english and give some small example data

Comment: Hello @MichaelDelgado yes you are right i should change the variables name